# Visual Studio 2017 SQL editor how to change keyboard shortcut to execute selection

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2017, if I open a .SQL file and connect to an instance of SQL Server, what is the name of the keyboard short to change that executes the statement.  Currently, if I hover over the green arrow, I see "Ctl+Shift+E", but I want it to be just Ctl+E, just as I have in SSMS.

I changed the keyboard shortcut for what I thought would be the command - SQL.TSqlEditorExecuteQuery and set it to Ctl+E, restarted VS yet the keyboard combination Ctl+E still does not respond and instead prompts me "*(Ctl+E) was pressed.  Waiting for second key of chord...*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut you are referring to (Ctrl+Shift+E) is: *TSql Editor Execute Query*

Here is how you can change shortcut keys:

> On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
>
> Expand the Environment folder, and then choose Keyboard.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change keyboard mapping for Execute Query from `CTRL+Shift+E` to `F5` (SSMS Style) in visual studio 2022 then options have slightly changed.

You'll see the following default settings
[image: Default Settings for Visual Studio 2022 TSQL Query Execute in Editor]

Change it to `F5` by pressing keyboard key and do the following settings as shown ahead and don't forget to click on `Assign` button

[image: Change keyboard mapping of query editor in visual studio 2022]

This will not override the default debug `F5` if you are not in query editor and will be only active if your T-Sql editor is in focus and I hope this is the default behaviour that you would want as well.